# Is it possible to request only a subset of the scopes for which a user has granted consent in Azure AD OAuth2 implicit flow?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I created an app registration, let's call it API with app id URI = api://dummyapi, with read and write scopes.
On the initial request from another app registration, let's call it client, I got the token after user's consent with token's scp(scope) = "read write" using the below request:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={client app id}
&response_type=token
&redirect_uri=http://localhost
&scope=api://dummyapi/read api://dummyapi/write
&response_mode=fragment
```

For future access token requests, is it possible to request a token with **only the read scope**?
While testing the below request with scope as read only, I get an access token with scp = "read write".

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={client app id}
&response_type=token
&redirect_uri=http://localhost
&scope=api://dummyapi/read
&response_mode=fragment
```

I was thinking of a scenario where the UI client app has a readonly and read-write mode, and it can request for a token with scp=read for readonly mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Azure AD will issue an access token with all of the granted delegated permissions for the requested resource, granted on behalf of the signed-in user.

[The only exception to this](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/whats-new-archive#unrequested-but-consented-permissions-will-no-longer-be-added-to-tokens-if-they-would-trigger-conditional-access) is if the client app dynamically requests permissions, and one of the granted permissions which was *not* requested were to trigger a conditional access challenge.

(The rest of this answer is just additional details about that exception.)

To better understand this exception, consider an example where an app has been grated User.Read, Mail.Read, and Files.Read.All, and the customer has a conditional access policy requiring multi-factor authentication when accessing mail (but not when accessing files), and the user has not already performed MFA:

- If the app requests `scope=.default`, then conditional access *will* be enforced, and User.Read, Mail.Read, and Files.Read will be included in the token.
- If the app uses `scope=User.Read Mail.Read`, then again, conditional access will be enforced and again the token will include all three permissions. Note that Files.Read.All was not explicitly requested, but it was granted and including it would not trigger any additional conditional access challenges.
- If the app requests `scope=User.Read` then MFA will *not* be required, and the token will include only User.Read and Files.Read.All. Note that Mail.Read is *not* included because it was not explicitly requested and including it would have triggered a conditional access challenge. Also note that Files.Read.All *was* included, because although it was not explicitly requested, it was granted and including it would not trigger additional challenges.