# Token is generating with all the available scopes in AzureAD

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, authorization, azure-authentication

I have below setup on Azure,

1. Host APP

   - Added 3 Scopes under "Expose an API" tab i.e. abc, def, ghi
2. Client APP

   - Added all 3 Scopes under "API Permissions" tab

Now if I request the token from Postman for Client APP with specific scope(s) and I decode the token over JWT.IO then I all 3 scopes available in "scp" claim.

POSTMAN Setup for OAuth 2.0,

[image]

**My expectation here is to implement scope based authorization where If I request the token for abc scope then only ABC should present in token.**

Comment: Same thing seems to be working fine when I request the token with sending client id of host app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check these:

1. AFAIK ,At this point of time, azure ad access token consists of all
   the granted delegated permissions for the requested resource,
   granted on behalf of the signed-in user.
2. ***If you have added the permissions under API permissions blade of the app and granted admin consent, you will get those permissions in
   the token even if you do not explicitly specify within your token
   request.*** Please remove the permissions from there if not required
   and just keep the scopes under Expose an API blade only if not
   required to grant directly.
3. And the only  other reason they may not be present is, if the scopes
   are not included in conditional access .Even if any one scope is
   requested that includes in conditional access, the rest scopes are
   directed to consent permissions and are present in the scope .
4. Please check this [Archive for What's new in Azure Active Directory?
   | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/whats-new-archive#unrequested-but-consented-permissions-will-no-longer-be-added-to-tokens-if-they-would-trigger-conditional-access) regarding Unrequested but consented permissions
   will no longer be added to tokens if they would trigger Conditional
   Access

   For better understanding please check this  [SO ref - ***Is it possible
   to request only a subset of the scopes for which a user has granted
   consent in Azure AD OAuth2 implicit flow?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70380010/is-it-possible-to-request-only-a-subset-of-the-scopes-for-which-a-user-has-grant?rq=1)  In that as said by
   @Philippe ,see different cases where  example is given when an app
   has already granted User.Read, Mail.Read, and Files.Read.All, and
   the customer has a conditional access policy requiring multi-factor
   authentication when accessing mail (but not when accessing files),
   and the user has not already performed MFA

See microsoft identity platform scopes, permissions, & consent section [example 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#example-1-the-user-or-tenant-admin-has-granted-permissions) , [ex2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#example-2-the-user-hasnt-granted-permissions-between-the-client-and-the-resource) & [client-credentials-grant-flow-and-default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#client-credentials-grant-flow-and-default) says ( Issuing a client credentials request by using individual application permissions (roles) is not supported. All the app roles (application permissions) that have been granted for that web API are included in the returned access token.

**References:**

1. [Microsoft Azure AD JWT Token is missing Scope information -
   Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/256281/microsoft-azure-ad-jwt-token-is-missing-scope-info.html?msclkid=d32fd0f3d05711ec8fe9ac90441a963c)
2. [Microsoft identity platform scopes, permissions, & consent -
   Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#the-default-scope)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this helps. Currently we are blocked for API to API communication where we have 2 APIs (Ex. A and B) which is exposed to consumers but we do call WebAPI B from WebAPI A and we have scopes based auth in place for all our APIs. We generate token with Client Credential grant when we do call API B from API A, with Client Creds token Scopes are not being returned in token so call to API B is not not authorizing as scopes are missing in token.

Can you please help us here.